# Search a file on all volumes in the computer

Tags: windows-10, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to search for a file on all volumes on my computer

I was not successful with the answer from this link:
[get-childitem-with-multiple-paths-via-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58415043/get-childitem-with-multiple-paths-via-variable)

I tried:
`$Location = 'c:\*', 'd:\*', 'e:\*'`

How do I search for a file on all volumes on my computer?

Comment: `(Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem).Root | % { Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Include yourfile.ext -File -Recurse -ErrorAction Ignore }`

Comment: @leeharvey1 Also works, but search took 3 min longer than the solution I found, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$location = "c:\*", "d:\*", "e:\*" `
| % {$_;Get-ChildItem -Recurse $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Include *.txt | ...Commands according to your logic` | 
Out-File "C:\YourOutput\Path\File\List.txt" -Append }
```